# How to get running total by ranges?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How to get a running total based on range:

```
name, Level, value, runningtotal;
A             5      5;
B     1       3     10;
B     2       2     10;
C             1     11;
```

Comment: I need running total based on name, if name is repeating then it should consider the max level for running total for that name.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what column you are doing your running total on. But in 2008 the best way of doing a running total is a self join like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test(
    ID      INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    AValue  INT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1,4), (2,2), (3,18)

SELECT T1.ID, T1.AValue, SUM(T2.AValue) RunningTotal
FROM #Test T1
JOIN #Test T2 ON T1.ID >= T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.AValue

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Comment: I need running total based on name, if name is repeating then it should consider the max level for running total for that name.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte(name,value) as
(
select name,sum(value) as val from A group by name
)
,
    cte2 as
    (
    SELECT c.name,SUM(b.value) as val
    FROM   cte c inner join
           cte b
    on b.name <= c.name
    GROUP BY c.name
    )
    select c.name,c.value,b.val from A c inner join cte2 b on c.name=b.name 
    order by c.name
```